# Inserting huge data From one Table to Another Table

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I have a scenario. I have data of 10000 in my table A. I need some of the data to be copied to table B.
Currently, iam doing inner join by comparing 3 columns and doing.
But most of the times my database crashes

What is the efficient way of comparing and doing that?

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING AS CWS
    INNER JOIN CONTENT_WORKFLOW_MASTER CWM 
        ON CWM.PROGRAM_ID = CWS.PROGRAM_ID 
            AND CWM.SOURCE_GROUP_NAME = CWS.SOURCE_GROUP_NAME 
            AND CWM.COPY_CULTURE = CWS.COPY_CULTURE
            AND CWM.USER_LOCKED = 0
            AND CWS.IS_PROCESSED = 0
WHERE CWS.INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID="cea56114-bf6c-46c5-ac67-edbdf67‌​6a86d" 
    AND CWS.GUID="xxx";
```

Comment: Please post the query you are using. Also...10000 is not a huge amount of data unless your join is not correct and you basically end up multiplying the table by itself.

Comment: SELECT * FROM CONTENT_WORKFLOW_STAGING AS CWS
INNER JOIN CONTENT_WORKFLOW_MASTER CWM ON CWM.PROGRAM_ID = CWS.PROGRAM_ID
AND CWM.SOURCE_GROUP_NAME = CWS.SOURCE_GROUP_NAME
AND CWM.COPY_CULTURE = CWS.COPY_CULTURE
AND CWM.USER_LOCKED = 0
AND CWS.IS_PROCESSED = 0
WHERE  CWS.INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID="cea56114-bf6c-46c5-ac67-edbdf676a86d"
AND CWS.GUID="xxx";

Comment: Hi, Please find my query in the post. And yes my join is wrong. Debugging it. Help Me if you found

Comment: Will need to look at the table structure and data to analyze your joins.

Comment: Also include your server specs, OS and mysql.cnf file.

Comment: It's nothing but,I need to retrieve only the rows which have unique values for three columns across the two tables

Comment: The title says "Inserting", yet I don't see `INSERT`?  What do you really mean?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding index to my tables, but unfortunately its taking too long time to add. I even cleared the data in table. Is there any alternative way to add efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

`CWS` needs `INDEX(INTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID, GUID)`

`CWM` needs `INDEX(PROGRAM_ID, SOURCE_GROUP_NAME, COPY_CULTURE)`

If you need to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.